# Neo4j Connect Two or more nodes with same label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on connecting nodes with the same label values to show relationships.  However, when I run the code below, it's doing so, but also adding a relationship to itself as well as the other node with same name:

```
 MATCH (a:rec_sku), (b:rec_sku)
 WHERE a.also_bought_sku = b.also_bought_sku
 CREATE (a)-[r:SAME_SKU]->(b)
```

I also tried a more complex solution using nested loops, but ran into the same issue:

```
 MATCH (n:rec_sku)
 WITH collect(n) as plist
 FOREACH (x IN plist |
 FOREACH (y IN filter(z in plist WHERE x.also_bought_sku = z.also_bought_sku)      |
 CREATE (y)-[:SAME_SKU]->(x)
 )
 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid adding a self-relationship, just add a `WHERE` clause to filter:

```
MATCH (a:rec_sku), (b:rec_sku)
WHERE NOT a=b AND a.also_bought_sku = b.also_bought_sku
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:SAME_SKU]->(b)
```

You can also use the `CREATE UNIQUE` statement to ensure no duplicate relationships are created.